# JHipster updated entity with liquibase changelog

Tags: java, jpa, jhipster, liquibase

I started a project in JHipster 7.6. I generated my entities using jdl. Now I modified some of my entites in java. If I understand correctly, I have to generate a changelog for the liquibase and add it to the master xml. As is in the JHipster documentation I used the `./gradlew liquibaseDiffChangelog -PrunList=diffLog` command. The problem is that it generated a changelog, with the total database structure, and not just the changes. Could you say what am I doing or thinking wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It should work unless you use an in-memory h2 database. Alternatively, you could ask JHipster to generate only the diffs by using the `--incremental-changelog` option that was introduced in 7.0.0 https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/#would-you-like-to-use-incremental-liquibase-changelogs

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes I use H2 database in development. My question is that why the changelog generation depends on the database? I thought that the JPA plugin makes an abstraction for that. Could I use the alternative solution you proposed without using the jhipster generator cli? Is this available if it generated the project without the `--incremental-changelog` option. I tried to add it to the yo-rc.json in the form of  `"incrementalChangelog": true` but it dosent worked. Any suggestion?

Comment: Few misconceptions here. The changelog does not depend on the database. Liquibase does not use JPA, only JDBC because it does work at SQL level not entities.  For incremental logs, official doc is bad, see https://entando.com/page/en/how_to_use_liquibase_to_update_the_schema_of_your_jhipster_application?contentId=BLG5325&modelId=64